# Why does my application behave differently with Unity?

Tags: unity

[image: xlog when working as expected, outside of the Unity environment]

I'm the newly appointed application maintainer for a program called "xlog".  The program works fine in all but the Unity environment.  It is written using Gtk2.

I've never previously used Unity.  I noticed in Unity that the menu bar seems to be "redirected" to another place outside of my application GUI, to a bar at the top of the screen.  Secondly, one of the text entry boxes in my GUI is displayed as a thin line, unaccessible to the user except via the tab key.[image: xlog in unity - note the missing menu bar, and the remarks box isn't a box.]

If I take the xlog executable that works perfectly under Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and copy it to a 12.10 Unity distribution, I see the different behavior.

I haven't a clue where to look, or what I should consider modifying, in the xlog application, to remedy this situation.  What's different in Unity that is unique to all other environments where this application works properly?

Comment: It may be advantageous to upload a couple of screenshots to highlight the issue.

Comment: Oli: It isn't obvious to me how to upload the screenshots.  This is my first time using this website.

Comment: Click the edit link, click the place in the post you would like the image to appear and then click the little icon in the toolbar that reads `img`. A pop-in should appear. Follow the prompts.

Comment: I tried that, Oli, but it says I need "10 reputation" to post images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I noticed in Unity that the menu bar seems to be "redirected" to
>   another place outside of my application GUI, to a bar at the top of
>   the screen.

I think what you are refering is the default behavior on Unity. Unity uses a global menu (the one you see at the top) similar to what is seen on OSX.

[image: Unity app menu in action.]

If you want this can be disabled in your application, but I think that is not very recommended: anyone using Unity will expect the menu not on the window, but at the top.

Regarding the entry box I would guess that it may be a problem with the Ubuntu theme. To check it try to change the Ubuntu theme (under "System Settings" -> "Appearance") and see if the box stays the same.

#### Edit

I was curious and looking at the code it seems that the problem is in your application.[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5662887/) seems to fix the issue (I can't enter a newline on that box, but I can't say if this is normal or a bug). Those values (100, 200) were selected randomly so this may not be the best way to solve that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Salem.  With the "High Contrast" theme, the Remarks box is displayed properly.  With the default Ambience theme, the Remarks box is not correctly displayed.

Comment: @AndyStewart see my edit.

Comment: Salem, I tried it locally and I see the differently sized remarks box.  I put the executable into my Virtual Box version of Ubuntu with Unity, and see that now the remarks box is behaving as expected.  I'll look at the inability to enter a <cr> - that behavior exists prior to your suggested modification.  Thank yoU!!!  You've been very helpful.  73 de Andy KB1OIQ

Comment: I just released xlog 2.0.7 with this fix.  Thanks, Salem, for your help!